# How to enter an exponent-formatted digit to the Xcode 8?

Tags: xcode, uibutton, xcode8

I am currently taking the free Standford Unversity IOS 10 development online course. For the first assignment, we were required to add a UIButton with operations such as xʸ, which computes x to the power of y. However, I found it impossible to enter the math symbol xʸ to my UIButton.
(PS: I could type "xʸ" here coz I copied and pasted it from somewhere else. But I really want to know a way to type it up within Xcode 8. I tried searching Emoji & Symbols, but still couldn't find anything helpful there)

Comment: Copy the the `xʸ` from your question and paste it into Xcode as needed. There's no magic needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

**Swift 3**

```
let font:UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:15)
let fontSuper:UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:8)
let attString:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "xy", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:font!])
attString.setAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:fontSuper!,NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName:5], range: NSRange(location:1,length:1))
Btn.setAttributedTitle(attString, for: .normal)
```

Comment: None of this is needed. Just type `xʸ` as the button's title.